# Let A and B be independent events such that P(A) = P(B) and P( AuB) = 0.5. Then P(A) =?

Tags: probability

I tried solving this using $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) -P(A \cap B). $ I obtained the quadratic equation $2x - x^2=0.5. $ When I solved the equation where $x= P(A),$  I got the root values as 2.414 and 0.414. But the answer is 0.2929. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Could someone explain how to solve this?

Comment: In your quadratic equation, there is a sign flipped: it should be
$$
P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = 2x - x^2 = 0.5.
$$

Comment: Correct... It was a typing mistake

Comment: That probably explains the discrepancy between what you got in the computations and the provided answer, no?

Comment: No. I solved it by taking 2x - x^2= 0.5. while typing out my doubt here, I made a mistake.

Comment: I get $$
x = 1 \pm {1 \over \sqrt{2}}.
$$

Comment: I got 1 + sqrt(2) and 1-sqrt(2) as the roots. Is that what you got too ? I couldn't make out from the above comment

Comment: No.  I transform the quadratic to $2x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0$, which gives me discriminant
$$
D = 16 - 8 = 8
$$
and, accordingly, the roots
$$
x = { 4 \pm \sqrt{8} \over 4} = 1 \pm {1 \over \sqrt{2}}.
$$

Comment: Ok. I got it. Its correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.

Given $P(A)=P(B)=x$,

so $x+x-(x\times x)=0.5\Rightarrow 2x-x^2=\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow 4x-2x^2-1=0$.

We have to solve, $2x^2-4x+1=0$. Here, 
$a=2,b=-4,c=1$.

Now,$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{4\pm\sqrt{16-4\times2\times(-1)}}{2\times2}=\frac{4\pm\sqrt{8}}{4}=1\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

We have $x=1.707 \& 0.292$.

$\because, x $ is probability $x {\not>} 2$.

$\therefore \boxed{x= P(A)= 0.292}$